# Special Character in xml

Tags: c#, regex, xml, linq

I have a data object which I'm serializing to xml:

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(obj));
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");
    serializer.Serialize(sw, item, ns);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

My xml stored in the DB looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ITEM>
    <FIELD name="INDEX" value="3" />
    <FIELD name="NAME" value="name1" />
    <FIELD name="DESC" value="ab % c ^" />
    <FIELD name="desc2" value="des %sd$" />
    <FIELD name="desc3" value="desc3" />
</ITEM>
```

While I'm using this xml for some other work I having problem with the special characters. If I replace the special characters like `$` with `&#36;`

I do have two questions:

- Is there any way when I replace this character in my xml while
  serializing?
- How can I replace all attributes special
  character values only, not tags without using loops?

I do know how to use foreach attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by "i having problem"? It should be fine, as it's valid XML. You should look into fixing whatever code is having problems with that XML.

Comment: Do you just want to convert XML strings that you've read in using something other than an XML parser back into normal strings?

Comment: `while i using this xml for some other work i having problem because special character` Could you serialize the xml as usual and then replace the characters while moving the data into a new object specifically for your other code? I wouldn't change the xml data itself because of a consumer needing the data in a different format. It should be up to the consumer to change the data afterwards for its specific use.

Comment: above xml store in string variable and we calling wcf service where its failing but i dont have that code so i need to correct from my side .

Comment: As @JonSkeet said the above XML is valid. You can verify this here: http://xmlgrid.net/validator.html The WCF Service needs to be fixed it is unable to read valid XML.

Comment: but  as i said before if i replacing $ with &#36; working fine . so there is something to do with special character , and i saw so many post about removing/escaping/replacing   special charter from xml .

Comment: or there is any suggestion where i can change value of every tag of xml using linq or something , i have around 1000 tag so i cant name it , or is there no other way than loop all attributes .

Comment: You say "we calling wcf service" - the "we" suggests that even if you're not normally responsible for that code, it's code within your company... so work to try to get it fixed. Always try hard to solve a problem rather than working round it.

Comment: @Dilip Are you not trying to miss-representing data? If your XML represents data from a data store, how does your caller know `&#36` is suppose to be `$`? What if the caller expects a description in the item containing `$` or what if you initial Data has `&#36` in it to begin with? In my humble opinion, by not addressing the issue at the right place you are coupling separate parts of the application too much together as they must now share internal knowledge and worst scenario, possibly introduce more problems going forward.

Comment: i understanding everyone view but somewhere i stuck as i dont have other part of code otherwise i would have fixed that .  believe me before writing question i tried all possible scenario from my side

Comment: @Fran - that application also parse the xml so user will see always $  , but while data transfer i need to do special character replace .